# Photoshop help to reduce the PSD file size without losing its quality and to create a fast loading page?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

I have beeen working on a website design into a psd format , the file size reached around 300 megabytes.... So is my PSD file as intial design reaching this size is terrible !
I need to end up with fast loading page , Right now is should be loading in 80sec @ 65kbps
any hints or fixing guides will assure me and i would be Thankful to everyone.
my project is to create my user interface (looks like facebook as a live example that everyone knows)

Comment: 1489 Pixels X 1516 Pixels till now , is this a correct optimum for any screen , laptop or Desktop computers , i am sorry i am still a new web designer =) ,
Resolution 72

Comment: @MephistonX Would be good to have that posted as an answer, even if it's 'correcting' the question.

Comment: If possible, it would be helpful to post a screenshot of the layout so we can help identify elements that could potentially be re-worked as CSS elements to reduce using images as a crutch. Also, PSD file size should not be indicative of the size it will be when formatted as a web page. PSD format offers very little compression. When properly structured in HTML/CSS, the page should be drastically smaller in filesize

Comment: This question is essentially asking "How do I build web sites?" A valid question, but way too broad for SE.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer If you want to discuss your previous comment, please use the meta or the chat.

Comment: When you make websites in photoshop, usually you save small pieces of the image and load them with html from your site. For instance you would save the header-area without the buttons in photoshop and then load that image as a background and use html/css to make responsive buttons.

Answer (score 3):

for a start you won't/should'nt be using your psd on your website. you should be saving out elements of your psd (as compressed files such as png-8s etc.) and combining them with HTML & CSS to create the website - this will drastically reduce the total load of the website. Also what dimensions are you working to in your psd - as they may be too large for web use (equally what dpi is your psd set to - for web purposes 72 us the standard)

Comment: Thank you , i have a good answer with a picture but i cannot submit it for helping people like me because of everyone vote down , the question is specific enough.

Comment: post a link to picture, upload it to imageshack or something. Once you have done it someone here would post it for you.

Comment: Thank you , where are you from? your name is arabic one =)